# Can't restart SearchUI.exe through CMD

Tags: command-line

When I try the following command:

```
net stop searchUI.exe
```

It says "The service name is invalid". Why? How can I fix it?

Comment: Open task manager, go to the services tab, do you see a service named `searchUI`?

Comment: The service name is not the same as the executable name. You can find out the details of services with `sc query` or by using the GUI `services.msc`.

Comment: Indeed, the service name is wsearch, not searchui.exe. Thanks!